# Need help making 2 divs overlap with a svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to get the bottom div to overlap onto the top one with a wavy svg to make it look like that the bottom div has a wavy line on it that overlap the top div

but this is what I get
[image]

I have tried to fix it but I cant seem to figure it out
HTML

```css
 * {
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
    }
    .header-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
    }
    
    .header-top {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: #3C8DAD;
    }
    
    .header-bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: #F5A962;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header-top"></div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
            <path fill="#F5A962" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L48,192C96,192,192,192,288,186.7C384,181,480,171,576,192C672,213,768,267,864,261.3C960,256,1056,192,1152,176C1248,160,1344,192,1392,208L1440,224L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path>
            </svg>
            <div class="header-bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please try `svg{display:block}`

Comment: just tried it it removed the line between the svg and the div now there is white space between the top div and the svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure about your final goal, but from what you have, you can either reset display or vertical-align on svg, and simply set the blue background to the parent container.
Thats not really an answer but a comment with a demo also asking you to clarify your final use . The SVG could also be send to the background over a gradient.

from your code and little CSS modification :

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #3C8DAD;
}

.header-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

svg {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.header-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #F5A962;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header-top"></div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
            <path fill="#F5A962" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L48,192C96,192,192,192,288,186.7C384,181,480,171,576,192C672,213,768,267,864,261.3C960,256,1056,192,1152,176C1248,160,1344,192,1392,208L1440,224L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path>
            </svg>
  <div class="header-bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Setting an height of 1000px + 2containers of 50% of height and drop an svg there might not be what your after ;), at least for the possible use of the markup

Comment: that's what I want but I tested it and its only working in Firefox

Comment: @AndrewSaenger strange, that snippet works in chrome and edge. For IE 11 `svg {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:-70% 0
}` is required to reduce svg's height virtually to 0 or less. About safari, i guess the IE11 requirement could also be necessary (it makes sens 50% + 50% + svg is hover 100% ... also the reason why i wander what is your final use  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to eliminate the border of the svg file

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you need but I think something like [this.](https://codepen.io/cyberburi/pen/eYWrKyr?editors=1100)

Try this styles

```
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #3c8dad;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.header-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #f5a962;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

with this HTML

```
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header-top">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
      <path fill="#F5A962" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L48,192C96,192,192,192,288,186.7C384,181,480,171,576,192C672,213,768,267,864,261.3C960,256,1056,192,1152,176C1248,160,1344,192,1392,208L1440,224L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="header-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
}

.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}

.header-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #3C8DAD;
}

.header-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #F5A962;
}
```

I believe this is what you want to do: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kengru/pen/VwbxdxZ).

The issue is that HTML treats the SVG as any other tag and tries to put it on the screen on the order of the defined elements.

In order to overlap an element with another, you have to play around the `position` css property, in this case, I made it `absolute` and then defined the position, this works ok because you have a fixed height for the container.